# Submitting a completely different IOS App but with same Bundle ID

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

My team has an app that was developed with react-native. We are now contemplating creating a new version with native iOS technology and language (Swift). I want to make sure before we start developing, that Apple will accept an app that is completely new in every way, but that has the same bundle Id.

Is this the case?

Comment: edited to remove xcode. I see that often on SO and there is no connection about version of xcode and the content of the app. Apple doesnt really care. xCode is only the IDE we use to develop the app!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have done this with our old app. We just replaced our new app with old one and apple has accepted that..

Answer (score 1):

No problem at all.

However when you submit that app for review, you should make sure to set the checkbox that this version contains major changes. Otherwise you run chances of Apple rejecting that version.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the case?

Yes. Apple doesn’t know or care how the source code changes. Language, frameworks, architectures, interface, functionality — obviously all such choices must be free to evolve.